# Can LittleFs read and write binary files?

Tags: c, embedded, filesystems, microcontroller

```c
// File open flags
enum lfs_open_flags {
    // open flags
    LFS_O_RDONLY = 1,         // Open a file as read only
#ifndef LFS_READONLY
    LFS_O_WRONLY = 2,         // Open a file as write only
    LFS_O_RDWR   = 3,         // Open a file as read and write
    LFS_O_CREAT  = 0x0100,    // Create a file if it does not exist
    LFS_O_EXCL   = 0x0200,    // Fail if a file already exists
    LFS_O_TRUNC  = 0x0400,    // Truncate the existing file to zero size
    LFS_O_APPEND = 0x0800,    // Move to end of file on every write
#endif

    // internally used flags
#ifndef LFS_READONLY
    LFS_F_DIRTY   = 0x010000, // File does not match storage
    LFS_F_WRITING = 0x020000, // File has been written since last flush
#endif
    LFS_F_READING = 0x040000, // File has been read since last flush
#ifndef LFS_READONLY
    LFS_F_ERRED   = 0x080000, // An error occurred during write
#endif
    LFS_F_INLINE  = 0x100000, // Currently inlined in directory entry
};
```

Here it is read, write, and append, but can it be similar to C's fopen to open files with rb, wb binary file?

I try to use directly `LFS_O_WRONLY | LFS_O_CREAT`   to write and use `LFS_O_RDONLY` to read.

Comment: Generally on operating systems other than Windows text and binary mode are the same thing, there's no line ending or EOF translation.

Comment: Reading and writing in LFS is always "binary". It doesn't do any kind of translations like C `FILE` streams do in text-mode. I don't know of any low-level file API that does.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Please write an actual answer, if you know for sure. You might want to add a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

[The GitHub page](https://github.com/littlefs-project/littlefs) says:

> Once mounted, the littlefs provides a full set of POSIX-like file and directory functions...

The POSIX file function using [`open`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), [`read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) and [`write`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) have no "text" mode. All files are read and written in "binary" mode.

So if LFS is "POSIX-like" then it also must do binary file reading and writing.

The text mode handling of `fopen` and its related reading and writing functions is done on a higher level, usually to translate OS-specific newline conventions.